# Sending a fake mouse click to an unfocused QLineEdit widget with PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5. I want to simulate a mouse click by a user on a specific QLineEdit widget programmatically, expecting the same behavior as for the real click.

The code below is my attempt, where this action is bound to a QPushButton. It works correctly when the QLineEdit widget `target` is focused. But if some other widget has focus when the button is pressed, both the focused widget and the `target` widget get the "focused" frame:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

What should I do to avoid this problem and perform a simulated click correctly?

Note: it is not clear to me why calling `.setFocus()` in `on_button_clicked` below is necessary. I thought that a mouse click on a widget with a Qt.StrongFocus focus property is sufficient to switch focus, but the simulated click seems to be completely ignored by the `target` widget if the focus is not manually switched.

---

```
import functools
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

app = QApplication([])
win = QMainWindow()
widget = QWidget()
win.setCentralWidget(widget)
layout = QVBoxLayout()
widget.setLayout(layout)

target = QLineEdit('Widget to be controlled')
layout.addWidget(target)

layout.addWidget(QLineEdit('(widget to test focus)'))

button = QPushButton('Click')
layout.addWidget(button)

def on_button_clicked(target):
    # This minimal example always uses the same position in the widget
    pos = QtCore.QPointF(25, 10)
    # Transfer focus, otherwise the click does not seem to be handled
    target.setFocus(Qt.OtherFocusReason)
    
    press_event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress, pos,
                                    Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
    target.mousePressEvent(press_event)
    release_event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease, pos,
                                      Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
    target.mouseReleaseEvent(release_event)

button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(on_button_clicked, target))
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

(If it helps or if there are easier ways to do this, the thing I am actually trying to do is to construct a widget which behaves almost like a QLineEdit, but completely ignores single mouse clicks (both press and release events), while the double click works like a single click on a QLineEdit. Transforming the double click event into a single click event on the underlying QLineEdit widget is the part I struggle with.)

Comment: I do not observe the behavior you indicate (I do not observe the blue border in the 2 QLineEdirs but only in one of them) in Linux with PyQt5 5.15.1 and python 3.8.2, what is your OS; pyqt5 version, python version, etc?

Comment: Interesting! I have recently started learning Qt, so I expected all problems to arise from my own code. The problematic behavior is on Mac OS Sierra (10.12.6), with python 3.9.0 and PyQt5 5.14.1. Apparently, forcing .repaint() on the activeWindow of QApplication after switching focus gets rid of the problem on the screenshot.